# How do I append Strings in SQL command

Tags: sql

In my sql script I am getting input. i want to add a prefix "_RO" to it. I tried following which did not work. The sql script will be executed using sql plus

```
DEFINE first = &1;
DEFINE second = &1 || '_RO'; -- did not work
DEFINE third  = CONCAT(&1,'_RO'); -- did not work
```

Please let me know if you know the solution.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  The solution will vary depending on the type.

Comment: If it's being executed in sql plus, it's probably oracle.  What are the details of "did not work"?

Comment: What if you try DEFINE second = first || '_RO'; for the second line?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server you must use `+` as concat operator.
In Oracle you user `||` as concat operator.